# Give equal items in list a unique number if items > 1

Tags: python, list

I made a functionality, but I not happy with the quantity of the code. The end result is good, but I believe it can be made much easier, only I don't know how.

The functionality: If equal items > 1 in list that all equal items getting unique set number.  Below I made an unit test for the end result. I'm not happy with the class `CreatSet`. Can somebody advise me how this can be implemented better.

```
import unittest


class Curtain(object):
  def __init__(self, type, fabric, number):
      self.type = type
      self.fabric = fabric
      self.number = number
      self.set_number = None

  def __str__(self):
      return '%s %s %s %s' % (self.number, self.type, self.fabric, self.set_name)

  def __eq__(self, other):
      return self.type == other.type and self.fabric == other.fabric

class CreatSet(object):
  def make_unique(self, original_list):
      checked = []
      for e in original_list:
          # If curtain: type and fabric is equal
          if e not in checked:
              checked.append(e)
      return checked

  def create_set(self, curtains):
      # Uniuqe items in list
      unique_list = self.make_unique(curtains)
      result = []
      for x in unique_list:
          # Create set list
          set_range = []
          for y in curtains:
              if y == x:
                  set_range.append(y)
          # Add set range into list
          result.append(set_range)

      # Create set number
      set_result = []
      set_number = 0
      for x in result:
          if len(x) == 1:
              set_result.append(x[0])
          else:
              set_number += 1
              for y in x:
                  y.set_number = set_number
                  set_result.append(y)
      # Return list ordered by number
      return sorted(set_result, key=lambda curtain: curtain.number)

class TestCreateSet(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
      self.curtains = []
      self.curtains.append(Curtain('pleatcurtain', 'pattern', 0))
      self.curtains.append(Curtain('pleatcurtain', 'plain', 1))
      self.curtains.append(Curtain('pleatcurtain', 'pattern', 2))
      self.curtains.append(Curtain('foldcurtain', 'pattern', 3))
      self.curtains.append(Curtain('pleatcurtain', 'plain', 4))
      self.curtains.append(Curtain('foldcurtain', 'plain', 5))
      self.curtains.append(Curtain('pleatcurtain', 'pattern', 6))
      self.curtains.append(Curtain('foldcurtain', 'pattern', 7))

   def test_auto_set(self):
      creat_set = CreatSet()
      result = creat_set.create_set(self.curtains)
      # Creating set
      self.assertEqual(result[0].set_number, 1)  # pleatcurtain, pattern
      self.assertEqual(result[1].set_number, 2)  # pleatcurtain, plain
      self.assertEqual(result[2].set_number, 1)  # pleatcurtain, pattern
      self.assertEqual(result[3].set_number, 3)  # foldcurtain, pattern
      self.assertEqual(result[4].set_number, 2)  # pleatcurtain, plain
      self.assertEqual(result[5].set_number, None)  # foldcurtain, plain
      self.assertEqual(result[6].set_number, 1)  # pleatcurtain, pattern
      self.assertEqual(result[7].set_number, 3)  # foldcurtain, pattern

 if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: This question should belong to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: i have a feeling a collections.Counter dict would do a lot of what your code is doing

Comment: Thx, I had great feedback in codee review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69485/assign-a-unique-number-to-duplicate-items-in-a-list. The solution is indeed counter.